# Adding an active class to a ul list in nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, nav, smooth-scrolling

I am trying to add a position indicator to my nav bar using the snippet below (i.e. a border should appear when a list item is selected). I currently have the rest of my css code nested using scss in the form nav{ li{/*code here */} a{/*code here*/}} and so on. When I add this active tag, nothing happens. Should I be formatting this differently with the active tag? Is there an easier way to do this? Why dosen't the active tag work? Thanks!!

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-main"> 
    <ul class="top-menu">
    <li id="home"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li id="about"><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li id="info"><a href="#media">MEDIA</a></li>
    <li id="social"><a href="#social">SOCIAL</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

CSS

```
#nav ul li .active {
border-bottom:3px #FFF solid;
}
```

JS

```
$(function() {
     var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href
.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
     $("#nav ul li a").each(function(){
          if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '' )
          $(this).addClass("active");
     })
```

Comment: I can't see any markup, but I could guess this is the correct selector: `nav ul li .active` and not `#nav`, unless you have a node with this ID (`nav`) in your page.

Comment: Please add any relevant HTML to your above code

Comment: You can debug this by sticking a breakpoint within your `.each()` loop or just inspecting the element you think would have the `active` class and see if it actually has it.

Comment: My first comment solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters the css is not targeting the element correctly. Your css is looking for an element with an `id` of nav, which doesn't exist.

The `nav` element has two classes (`navbar` and `navbar-main`), so you can use either to start off the selection. Because the jquery is adding a class of `active` to a matching link, the css rule would need to include `a`. To actually see the border, you'd also need to set a `display` property. One that is used quite often is `block`  e.g:

```
.navbar ul li a.active {
  display:block;
  border-bottom:3px #FFF solid;
}
```

In the example I've provided below, I've updated the jquery to target a specific link, just for illustration purposes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var pgurl = "#about"; //Using a static value for illustration purposes.
  $(".navbar ul li a").each(function(){
    if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '' ) {
      console.log($(this).attr("href"));
      $(this).addClass("active");
    }
  });
});
```

[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/5y1jxaxm/1/)

Comment: Thanks! How would you adopt this to react to clicking any of the links? Adding window.location.href.substr(window.location.href
.lastIndexOf("/")+1); to your snipped causes it to fail.

Comment: My snippet was just an example. You won't be able to query the window location because the content is in an `iframe`. In a working environment, you'd need to register a click event and execute the desired actions e.g. removing the `active` class from a prior selection and adding it to the newly selected link.

Comment: Can you explain how I would go about doing that? I know how to get a line to appear, I'm having trouble with getting things to change selection.

Comment: I can see a chameleon question coming over. If this answer solves your original problem, mark it as the solution. If you have further problems/questions, create new posts (but search the forum for similar questions before doing so).

Answer (score 0):

Below code will find all `<a>` tag whose `href` attribute contains the current pathname.

```
$(function () {
        $("a[href*='" + location.pathname + "']").addClass("active");
})
```

Comment: I would like to understand how your code answers the relevant questions from the above post: **Should I be formatting this differently with the active tag? Is there an easier way to do this? Why dosen't the active tag work?**

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you. That's how I use mine.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $(".top-menu > li > a[href*='" + location.pathname + "']").addClass('active'); //the .top-menu is your ul class
});(jQuery);
```